# Mock HTTP Error response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service that does the following:

```
  public fetchStuff(): Observable<MyModel> {
    const url = `httpURLHere`;

    return this.httpClient.get(url, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        console.warn(res);
        if ((res.status === 200 && res.body === null) || res.status === 404) {
          throw new Error("Error getting stuff");
        } else if (res.status === 500) {
          throw new Error("Error with API");
        } else {
          return <MyModel>res.body;
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);

    return new ErrorObservable(error.message || error);
  }
```

I want to be able to test the logic inside the `fetchStuff()` function; this is proving to be more difficult than I first thought, though--since using:

`httpMock.expectOne(url).error(new ErrorEvent('ERROR'), { status: 404 });`

skips the inside logic and jumps straight to the `handleError()` function; and:

`httpMock.expectOne(url).flush(null, { status: errorStatus, statusText: 'ERROR' });`

will put the `{status, statusText}` in the `body` of the response.

I can't find anything anywhere else on how to mock an error response without jumping straight to the `handleError()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. As the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling) documentation states anything other than 2XX-3XX response code are handle as error:

> Two types of errors can occur. The server backend might reject the request, returning an HTTP response with a status code such as 404 or 500. These are error responses.
>
> Or something could go wrong on the client-side such as a network error
> that prevents the request from completing successfully or an exception
> thrown in an RxJS operator. These errors produce JavaScript ErrorEvent
> objects.
>
> The HttpClient captures both kinds of errors in its HttpErrorResponse
> and you can inspect that response to figure out what really happened.

So basically your condition in `map` is dead code.